# OG: dynamically generated with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to dynamically generate og: parameters for social media sharing on a blog I own and I am getting pretty stuck on one major issue.

I am generating meta tags with this code:

```
<head>
    <?php include 'head.php';   ?>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $textnews ?>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $imgurl ?>" />
</head>
```

I am getting the vars $title, $textnews, $imgurl from a sql database each time I load the page article. If I inspect the page with Google dev, everything is fine and displays nicely where it needs to be. When I use facebook's debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ it says that it can't detect the content of my content="...".

I believe that, as my url is dynamically generated with parameters such as ?title?subtitle, they get removed and that facebook only scraps ind_article.php without the parameters and so without the content="" filled according to the url.

Anyone did experience this kind of problem and can help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you include in your head.php? you should put the metatags first, before you add countless css or js files, for example.

Comment: @luschn right, but would this have an effect on the og: generation?

Comment: Facebook takes what you specify as og:url to be the _real_ URL for this piece of content. If you have your parameters in there, then they won’t be “removed”, and your problem must be something else. // Please give actual example URLs in such cases, so that we can check the actual debugger results ourselves.

Comment: @CBroe http://neonmex.ch/ind_article.php?non-mex-90-ans-d039histoire?histoire-et-non this URL for example renders the correct og:url but let other og: empty...

Comment: all those tags are empty when i open the source in the browser, escept for og:url. also, there are 2 head sections and there is a script tag after the body...

Comment: You are passing parameters in a weird way here. When you said parameters, I assumed you meant a normal query string with name=value pairs, not whatever this is supposed to be. Try that first.

Comment: Ouille, fixed the parameters and all of a sudden the Facebook scraper gets my og: fields perfectly in the debugger. But still not when pressing the social facebook icon.